# How do I center a frame within a frame in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, frame

I have a frame that I fixed the size of using the `grid_propagate()` method. I'd like to center a frame within this frame. How do I go about this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

pack it to fill in all directions. Add padding as needed.

Or, use place which lets you use relative or absolute positioning. You can use a relative x/y of .5/.5 and an anchor of "c" (center).

```
import Tkinter as tk

root=tk.Tk()
f1 = tk.Frame(width=200, height=200, background="red")
f2 = tk.Frame(width=100, height=100, background="blue")

f1.pack(fill="both", expand=True, padx=20, pady=20)
f2.place(in_=f1, anchor="c", relx=.5, rely=.5)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It is slightly confusing as neither f1 nor f2 declare a parent. How does f1 know to get packed in root? Also, 2 different geometry managers are being mixed. This is warned against everywhere as bad practice. However, it works, and solves a problem I have been stuck with for hours. So +1!

Comment: @wsaleem: Every window except the root window must have a parent. The root window is the default when a widget doesn't explicitly specify a parent. As for mixing pack and place (and/or grid): that's quite all right -- even preferable -- in an application as a whole. You just can't mix them in the same containing window. In this case `f1` is being managed by the root window and `f2` is being managed by `f1` (because of the `in_` parameter.

Comment: `place()` is fine when you already have to force the size of the outer frame. But normally I avoid `place()` because the frame does not "sense" the size of `placed` widgets when autosizing.  Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to center a widget (like a frame) inside a frame, the easiest way to do it is via `.grid()`.  If you use `.pack()`, you end up stuck along one of the edges, since `pack()` has the `side` keyword.

If you use `.place()`, then you're stuck forcing the size of the outer frame (which normally you don't have to do, but you've already done it, so it's not an issue), because `placed` widgets aren't detected when the frame autosizes like with `packed` or `gridded` widgets. I'm not sure why, but that's the way it is.

So, in general, the best way to center a widget inside a frame is to `grid` the widget into the frame. (The `sticky` option defaults to CENTER.) And then, if you want to be able to resize the outer frame and have the widget stay centered, you need to allow the outer frame's cell to expand/grow. You would do this via the `.grid_rowconfigure()` etc commands. So, an example might be:

```
        widget = Widget(frame, ...)
        widget.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="")
        frame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
```