# Parent/master vs. in_ in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

Examine the following code:

```
import Tkinter as tk

root=tk.Tk()
f1 = tk.Frame(width=200, height=200, background="red")
f2 = tk.Frame(width=100, height=100, background="blue")

f1.pack(fill="both", expand=True, padx=20, pady=20)
f2.place(in_=f1, anchor="c", relx=.5, rely=.5)

root.mainloop()
```

Taken from: [How do I center a frame within a frame in Tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4241036/how-do-i-center-a-frame-within-a-frame-in-tkinter)

One of the comments there says `"The root window is the default when a widget doesn't explicitly specify a parent"` and also `" In this case f1 is being managed by the root window and f2 is being managed by f1 (because of the in_ parameter)."`

What is the difference between the hierarchy created by the master parameter used in the instantiation of new widgets and the hierarchy created by the the in_ prameter used in the .place layout manager?

Why is f2 not being created as a child of f1? (and would it change anything?)

Comment: The `in_` arg to `.place` (or `.pack` or `.grid`) only affects the _placement_ of the widget. Your `f2` still has `root` as its master, if you do `print(f1.master, f2.master)` you'll see ` . .`, which shows that they both have the root window as their master.

Comment: yes, but what is each of the two used for? when would it make sence for an object to to be in_ his master / parent ?

Comment: If you want a  widget to be placed inside its master then you wouldn't bother with the `in_` arg. You use `in_` when you have a bunch of widgets that you want to treat as one logical group controlled by a single parent, but you want to place them into several different Frames (or other containers). There's a reference for this in the docs, but "in" isn't an easy keyword to search for. ;) If I could find a decent reference I'd write a proper answer...

Comment: I though that if i have a frame and want to place two labels in it like pack() would, but using place instead I should be able to do so by placing the second label using label2=Label(fr1, text="Hello world ", bg="red").place(in_=label1, anchor=N, rely=1.0) but it seems to place it based on the height of f1 and not that of label2.

Comment: Sorry, I can't help with that. The `.place` layout method is a bit quirky, and it's generally advised to use `.grid` or `.pack` instead. You can certainly use `in_` with `.grid` or `.pack`, but I don't think there's any way to put another widget inside a Label because it's not a container for widgets, you can only put text or an image into it.

Comment: maybe you have a point there in your last statement. I was thinking of "in_" as being "with_respect_to_the_following_widgets_coordinate_system"..
what widgets other then frame can be considered valid values for "in_" ? (i.e. containers) ?

Comment: no, sorry I got carried away, I am not trying to place stuff in a label nor with respect to it.
I will leave this Q trying to get a general answer to parent v.s. in_ and I have created the following Q with a specific example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46524030/tkinter-placement-of-widgets where it seems someone has already provided me with an answer i need to check.

Comment: @PM2Ring: yes you can place another widget inside a `Label`. You can also place them inside an `Entry`, a `Checkbutton`, etc. There's rarely a reason to, but tkinter allows it.

Comment: @BryanOakley Interesting! Thanks for that info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My lack of understanding seems to have been the result of a problem in my code for which I got an answer here:
[tkinter placement of widgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46524030/tkinter-placement-of-widgets)

Getting rid of the issue describe there I can now see that:

Master/parent: defines a bounding area limiting the *rendering* of its child widgets

in_: sets the widget on which the *positioning* of the in_(cluded) widget would be based

Answer (score 2):

> What is the difference between the hierarchy created by the master parameter used in the instantiation of new widgets and the hierarchy created by the the in_ prameter used in the .place layout manager?

The simple answer is that there is no hierarchy created by the `in_`  parameter. The only hierarchy is the parent/child relationship when the widget is created.

The `in_` parameter merely identifies a widget into which the other widget should be placed. It tells tkinter "make this child's placement relative to this other widget".

> Why is f2 not being created as a child of f1? (and would it change anything?)

It's not being created as a child because you didn't tell it to be a child. You didn't specify a parent, so tkinter uses the root window as the parent.

Would it change anything if you did? Not in this specific case. If `f1` did not fill the whole window, or filled it asymmetrically, `f2` would appear centered in `f1` but not centered in the window as a whole.