# Tkinter .pack() acting up

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I want to have a frame and I need to pack labels inside it but when i do it just screws everything up.

```
frame_1 = Frame(root, height=125, width=250, bg="white", highlightthickness=4).pack()
def add_label():
   label = Label(frame_1, text="text", bg="black", fg="White").pack()
```

and when I run the programm it looks like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/LECa1.png
note that the frame itself is white.

I don't understand why it won't pack it in the frame but instead below it...

Comment: One thing that is wrong is the `frame_1 = Frame(root, height=125, width=250, bg="white", highlightthickness=4).pack()` statement is assigning `None` to the variable `frame_1` because that's what `pack()` always returns. See [Tkinter: AttributeError: NoneType object has no attribute <attribute name>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101750/tkinter-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-attribute-name).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tkinter: AttributeError: NoneType object has no attribute <attribute name>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101750/tkinter-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-attribute-name)

Comment: ***"I don't understand why it won't pack it in the frame"***: Your `frame_1` is `None` as described by @ martineau, therefore tkinter uses the default `root` as parent. Relevant [parent-master-vs-in-in-tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46521814/parent-master-vs-in-in-tkinter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: `pack_propagate(0)` should do the trick:
But before I have to say that `Frame(root, height=125, width=250, bg="white", highlightthickness=4).pack()` is wrong since it returns `none`. Use this:

```
frame_1 = Frame(root, height=125, width=250, bg="white", highlightthickness=4)
frame_1.pack()
```

Rest of the code:

```
frame_1.pack_propagate(0)    # this is the line that helps you

def add_label():
    label = Label(frame_1, text="text", bg="black", fg="White").pack()
add_label()
```

Tested on [Python IDLE](https://www.python.org/downloads/), v. 3.4.4

Hope that helped.